# Mass Replace differetent word using notepad ++

Tags: regex, replace, cpu-word, notepad++

I want to replace

```
<esi:include src="test"/>
```

to

```
<!--#include virtual="test"-->
```

I need mass replace with regex using notepad++

I'm at http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ can match the search wif below's regex

```
<esi:include src=|/>
```

But how to i mas replace all?

```
<!--#include virtual=|-->
```

seems not working. any idea? thanks

Comment: Something like [this](http://regex101.com/r/yS0pS1) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your find string needs to be this:

```
<esi:include src="([^"]*)"/>
```

The round brackets identify a subclause, which means "something I can use later.  What I've got in the subclause is "0 or more repetitions of any character that is NOT a double-quote"

So:

`(    )`    -- subclause

`[^"]`      -- any characther that IS NOT a double quote

`*`         -- 0 or more repetitions

Your replace is going to be this:

`<!--#include virtual="$1"-->`

Which is your text, but `$1` signifies where to put the subclause.

Comment: THANKS!i learnt something on regex already ! appreciate the answer. thankiu!

Answer (score 4):

Search for `<esi:include src=([^/]*)/>`

and replace with `<!--#include virtual=$1-->`

You can capture parts you want to reuse by putting round brackets around, that is called a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). You can then insert them in the replacement string by adding `$x`, where `x` is the number of the capturing group. The groups are numbered by the opening brackets.